# Using a firebase cloud function for SEO at root level

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

In my Angular 5 application I am using an Express app in combination with Firebase Cloud functions to render dynamic HTML markup for improved SEO purposes. Specifically for search crawler bots.

This works for all my routes except at root level (https://exampleapp.firebaseapp.com/) which serves the normal **index.html** instead of the result of my firebase function.

My **firebase.json** file looks like this:

```
  {
        "hosting": {
          "public": "dist",
          "rewrites": [
            {
              "source": "**",
              "function": "app"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

So all requests should be served by my app function. But why is this not the case for my root domain? Is there an extra step to ensure that the root is also included in this use case?

**Edit:**

And just to clarify I need the index.html file available in my dist folder to serve my users but I'm serving all crawlers with my express app which currently is working on all routes except the root domain.

Comment: See detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493514/11127383

Answer (score 1):

Remove the index.html from the public folder and it should be served from the function.

https://youtu.be/LOeioOKUKI8?t=13m53s

This video has a nice tutorial and the time refers to your issue specifically I would say.

Comment: I see where your coming from here but that doesn't seem to work. My dist folder holds the build for my application and if I delete the **index.html** out of that firebase deploy breaks the application.

Comment: I think you need to serve it from the firebase functions as detailed in the video after removing with all the required resources as if you are serving your normal index.html